# Delphi indy10 sockets data exchange on multiple forms

Tags: delphi, sockets

I am using indy10 sockets, and I ran into a small snag. I have my IdTCPServer on form one and I am wanting to send data from form 2 to remote location. I would think AContext.IOHandler.WriteLn() would work but in form 2 it throws errors and Identifier not found AContext.

It was simple to send and receive text on the client side. But, I am looking for a way to send text from the server on different form from the socket. If anything I will do a messy job and put invisible memo to send to then read the memo from there and send it off.

Comment: What you are asking for has been asked and answered many many many times in the Embarcadero and Indy forums over the years. Please search around.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track - using the `IOHandler` object of a given `TIdContext` - but you are looking in the wrong place for it.  From outside of the server's event handlers, you can access active `TIdContext` objects using the `TIdTCPServer.Contexts` property., which is a `TThreadList` of active connections.  To keep track of per-client data, such as login identifiers, you can use the `TIdContext.Data` property, or derive a new class from `TIdServerContext` and then assign it to the `TIdTCPServer.ContextClass` property.

Comment: I have been looking at those properties and I still cannot find what I am looking for.

Comment: `TIdTCPServer.Contexts` is a `TThreadList`. You have to call its `LockList()` method to get access to its underlying `TList` object. With that, you can loop through the list, casting each item to a `TIdContext` and then looking at its properties to see if it is the desired client that you want to send to. Once you have found the client, you can use its `TIdContext.Connection.IOHandler` to write to that client as needed.

Comment: How you actually identify each client is up to you to decide, based on your particular requirements. You could look at the remote IP/Port properties of the `TIdContext.Connection`, or you could store an object in the `TIdContext.Data` property that contains your own custom data, such as a username or other unique identifier that is assigned when the client connects and logs in to your server.